# How to get hours from date picker and calculate

Tags: jquery

How can i calculate the time between two date pickers, i'm currently using the date time picker from (dynarch)

The date times will look like so..

Txt2 = 01/07/2011 5:40:00 PM

Comment: Are you trying to do the calculation in front end or back end?

Comment: In the front end, if the user sets start time and then end time do the calculation to screen. In that kind of manner. Just so they can see what they are submitting. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your date part is in format mm/dd/yyyy, and you have your dates stored in the `txt1` and `txt2` vars, you should simply do:

```
var differenceInSeconds = (Date.parse(txt2) - Date.parse(txt1))/1000;
```

**EDIT** As you need in dd/mm/yyyy format, you can use the `Calendar.parseDate()` function from the [calendar api](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/doc/). So your code would be:

```
var differenceInSeconds = (Calendar.parseDate(txt2, false).getTime() - Calendar.parseDate(txt1, false).getTime())/1000;
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: My dates are stored the other way round DD/MM/yyy. Thank you

Comment: @webb, I've edited my post so it can handle DD/MM/yyyy date format.

Comment: Thanks, how do i call it to display on the page? Also if i want to subtracta number field like 0.25 how can i add it to the script on the fly. Thanks so much

Comment: to display it, let's say, inside a <div id="dif"></div> you'd do $("#dif").html(differenceInSeconds);